# Can you have || in Solidity Struct Data Types? and pass different .json or is there some way to accomplish below?

Tags: solidity

I have:

```
struct Extension {
  string URL;
  string Name;
}

struct Extension2 {
  int rank ;
  int year;
}
```

I'm looking to do the following:

```
struct x {
  Extension || Extension2 extension_;
}
```

I'm going to pass .json as

```
{
  "extension_": {
  "rank": 1,
  "year": 2023
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "extension_": {
  "URL": "https://www.google.com",
  "Name": "Google"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest structs to create more complex structs:

```
struct Foo {
 // members
}

struct Bar {
  // members
} 

struct FooBar {
  Foo f;
  Bar b;
}
```

You cannot use `||` to conditionally lay out a `struct/type`.

Depending on the intended usage, it may not matter. For example, if used as a storage pointer, there is no efficiency loss when only one of several possible substructures is populated. However, if used as `calldata` or `memory` then the overhead of unused sections would be inefficient.

Hope it helps.